# msrtool, ThrottleStop, cpupower how control cpu clock?

Tags: kernel, cpu, clock

I'm trying to control the clock of my notebook and I'm having a "half success" using cpupower I was able to limit the clock, but whenever a program (or better, marios programs) start to run and ask for more of the CPU the system ignores the limitation .

Speaking like that seems like it did not work, but in fact when the limit limits the cpu works inside it, but it also ignores when forced too much.

On windows I used ThrottleStop and only had this problem when there were "interruptions of the system" otherwise the cpu always ran within the limits imposed.

Does anyone have a solution that allows me to limit the clock and the system always respects this?

Comment: Please edit your post and add which CPU frequency scaling driver and governor you are using. An answer appropriate for you depends on that information. Do: `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver` and `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`. It might also help to know your processor: `grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo`.

Comment: Hi,
I have set up acpi-cpufreq and userspace manually.

https://pastebin.com/iDUBs0in

Comment: Since your processor is capable using the intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver, it would be easier to control using that driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are using the acpi-cpufreq CPU frequency scaling driver. This answer is for the intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver, with the suggestion that you go back to that driver for this work. Why? Because it is easier this way.

While your processor is a i3-2328M, examples herein are with a i7-2600K.

First, check your limits:

```
$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/*
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct:100
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct:42
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/num_pstates:23
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/status:active
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/turbo_pct:18
```

Now say, I wanted to limit my maximum CPU frequency to 60% of its capability:

```
echo 60 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct
```

I'll use turbostat to demonstrate:

```
sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,IRQ --interval 15
Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ     PkgTmp  PkgWatt
0.03    1606    844     26      3.69   <<< No load
0.80    3130    3492    26      4.50
3.91    3770    5791    39      9.53
12.52   3799    16078   41      22.84  <<< 100% load on one CPU
12.52   3799    16077   43      22.97
12.53   3309    16168   38      19.44
12.53   2300    16019   38      12.03  <<< Limit to 60% of max (to nearest P state)
12.53   2300    16069   37      12.03
12.53   2300    16007   38      12.03
100.00  2300    120463  43      33.79  << Increase load to all CPUs
100.00  2300    120467  44      33.81
12.53   2300    16045   38      12.04  << Decrease load back to only 1 CPU
12.53   2300    16053   38      12.04
3.34    2295    4756    31      5.95   <<< Load removed
0.03    1600    689     30      3.74
0.07    1816    885     33      3.76
```

Comment: I configured my rc.local with the commands to configure the governor for powersave and the clock between 800 and 1900 according to image, but as funny as it sounds, right now that the CPU reaches 100% the clock stays most of the time in 800 and jumps for a few seconds to 2200 instead of 1900. When I created the post I still did not restart the pc.

`modprobe cpufreq_powersave
cpupower frequency-set -g powersave
cpupower -c all frequency-set -d 800MHz
cpupower -c all frequency-set -u 1900MHz`

Comment: I don't completely follow. I never ever use any such tools (cpufreq_powersave, cpupower, ...) I only use primitive commands directly, as in my answer.

Comment: I'm doing a few tests, I came back with the intel_pstate driver and it did not change the clock in any way, but by chance I changed the clock-limit policy previously on the other drive, the CPU was limited to 1900mhz, which I have seen, but normally runs between 1900.

With the acpi drive, in powersave, the clock is always kept to a minimum, and from what I've noticed, jump to 1900 when you need it, and pass the time.

I noticed that running h265 in 1080 causes the cpu to ignore the limits completely (expected), h264 runs at the minimum of cpu and this probably works well for what I want.

Comment: At the time I asked a question, your answer had no effect, in fact not even cpupower had an effect, but in debian 10, yes, this method works, I remember testing it in the 4.x and 5.10 kernel backport, and both methods work.